# How to use the Inversions function?

Tags: functions

The `Inversions` function counts the number of inversions in permutation p.

More info: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/Inversions.html

When I try it, I didn't got a number as the result.

[image]

How to use it correctly?

Comment: In the future, please post your code *as text*, rather than as images.

Comment: OK, thank you for the suggestion. I'll follow it. @MarcoB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert your permutation from a cycles form into a positional form, and note that you need to provide the missing 3, which I've put in a separate cycle because it's unchanged by the permutation:

```
perm = FromCycles[{{1, 4, 2, 5}, {3}}];

ToInversionVector[perm]
(* returns: {4, 3, 2, 0} *)

Inversions[perm]
(* returns: 9 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Btw, where can I learn more about cycles form and positional form? I searched around and not sure if I'm on the correct documentation page.

Comment: The Combinatorica documentation isn't too detailed, but it has a `ToCycles[p]` function, so I guessed that the permutations were like this. Also, if you have a cycles expressed permutation with no other cycles like for example {1,2}, make sure to do `FromCycles[{{1,2}}]` with a double pair of {} to get the positional form.